# Pass Cloudflare Access with npm

Tags: authentication, npm, cloudflare

I'm running a Nexus server to host npm packages and i would like to protect it from direct exposure on internet using Cloudflare Access, which acts as pre-authentication / 2FA managed by Cloudflare.

For humans, the challenge is to enter in the Cloudflare pre-auth page an authorized email address, and then enter the temporary token that was sent to this email address. But this does not work for programmatic access, as with npm.

The solution in this case is to include specific headers in the http request to pass the Cloudflare authentication, as described in https://developers.cloudflare.com/access/setting-up-access/validate-jwt-tokens/

But i was wondering if adding this kind of headers is supported in npm, as it will be required to reach nexus and fetch packages when doing npm install.

Any search with npm, authentication, header, etc led me to pages describing how to perform authentication in nodejs, using various npm modules, but not how to do it in npm itself. Any clue?

Thanks.